# Swiper shows the second slide of the category, but the first should

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I have a slider with two categories of pictures Interior and Exterior. When you click on the Interior, the second slide with these photos is shown. The main problem is that column mapping is used. How to make the first photos in this category?

Example: `<` https://codepen.io/Gorotto/pen/XWpBYNY `>`

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Are you saying it's scrolling to the wrong image? If so, could you change it so the images look different, so it's easier to debug?

Comment: @DavidKnipe When you click on the Interior button, it shows not the first slide in which the pictures with the Interior began, but the next one where there are only pictures with the interior. The example shows the problem